# Store a state in a variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change some elements in variables and I'm using it with useState i can change it.

I just want to know quick answer of this.

this is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const BarChart = ({ title, label, changeLabels, changeDatas }) => {
  //////this is the states //////
  let data = {
    labels: changeLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: label,
        data: changeDatas,
        backgroundColor: [
          "#a7def8e1",
          "#7ec5e4ec",
          "#21a8e2eb",
          "#579deeeb",
          "#3165d4eb",
          "#3a68e77f",
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Bar
        data={data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: title,
              color: "#345fbb",
              font: { size: 22 },
            },
          },
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default BarChart;
```

I'm setting up the state on this variable. and using setState in the other component with useContext,

However,I just feel that it's not right things to do for some reason. It doesn't get any errors by the way .
Is it okay to use it like that??

Comment: You don't have a state, useState is never called, you're just passing some props to another component.

Comment: I think what you are calling "state" is very different from the concept of React state. It looks like you are just passing props on through to a child component. I don't see any overt issue here.

Comment: I need to put more details on this question .  Im not on computer now so i can't write more code. I meant the props is useState's state from another component Thank you for answering !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not React state, that's an object derived from the props, and that's absolutely fine.

You're not mutating any of the props internally or anything -- nothing wrong with your approach.

If computing that `data` object was more involved, you might want to use the `useMemo` hook, like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const BarChart = ({ title, label, changeLabels, changeDatas }) => {
  const data = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      labels: changeLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: label,
          data: changeDatas,
          backgroundColor: [
            "#a7def8e1",
            "#7ec5e4ec",
            "#21a8e2eb",
            "#579deeeb",
            "#3165d4eb",
            "#3a68e77f",
          ],
        },
      ],
    }),
    [changeLabels, changeDatas, label],
  );

  const options = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: title,
          color: "#345fbb",
          font: { size: 22 },
        },
      },
    }),
    [title],
  );

  return <Bar data={data} options={options} />;
};
export default BarChart;
```